# How do I use a JavaScript code to several classes with the same name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript, and to stack overflow, so excuse me if I am being oblivious. I was trying to built a progress bar for several classes with the same class name:

```
<div class="skill">
                <h4>Javascript</h4>
                <div class="progress-bar" data-label="Loading..." style="--width: 10">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="skill">
                <h4>Wordpress</h4>
                <div class="progress-bar" data-label="Loading..." style="--width: 10">
              </div>
              <div class="skill">
                <h4>Java</h4>
                <div class="progress-bar" data-label="Loading..." style="--width: 10">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="skill">
                <h4>Bootstrap</h4>
                <div class="progress-bar" data-label="Loading..." style="--width: 10">
                </div>
```

but the JavaScript code:

```
 const progressBar = document.getElementsByClassName
    ('progress-bar')[0]
    setInterval(() => {
      const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(progressBar)
      const width = parseFloat(computedStyle.getPropertyValue
        ('--width')) || 0
      progressBar.style.setProperty('--width', width + .1)
    },5)
```

was applied only to the first class:

```
<h4>Javascript</h4>
                <div class="progress-bar" data-label="Loading..." style="--width: 10">
                </div>
```

Where did I go wrong?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You went wrong by not paying attention to the docs and [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#examples) - specifically the 4th one down. Using array syntax `[0]` will limit the results to the first one. You will need to get them all and then iterate over them.

Comment: @charlietfl, I don't think that dupe reference is applicable here, as the OP has accessed element zero of the collection, so they are aware of the fact that it is an array-like value.

Comment: @trincot *"aware of"* .. perhaps not. Just figured the details on how to iterate are there and OP would see the path to follow. Along with MDN exaample of `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
('progress-bar')[0]
```

this will select the first item that it finds..
try this..

```
const pb = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar');
for(var i; i<pb.length ; i++)
{
   pb[i].//your codes for each item
}
```

Comment: Question isn't tagged jQuery and no sign of OP using it either. The selector you used is also invalid

Comment: yes, jquery makes it easier,though. the selector is also for example. many answers are here for using "each" in jquery..

Comment: I change the answer to use without jQuery!